# How to add crumb for each search result item?

Tags: 7, search, breadcrumbs

I want to add crumb/breadcrumb on each of search result item.

For example, if I search keyword **"dog"**, the search result should return results as follow.

---

Dog's Life ($title)
Dog is life. Dog is love... ($snippet)
Home > Article > Dog's Life (the crumb)

---

Dog Dog Who's There ($title)
Who's there dog? Dog dog dog... ($snippet)
Home > Tips Trick > Dog dog Who's There (the crumb)

---

Usually I construct the crumb using variable $url from `search_result.tpl.php` via function `mytemplate_preprocess_search_result()`, implemented in `template.php`.

I create a new variable, $breadcrumb, based on variable `$url` and then I call it on `search_result.tpl.php`. Then I copy `search_result.tpl.php` into my theme folder.

The problem arises when it is no longer achievable to construct crumb from `$url` due to circumstances, mostly because of custom breadcrumb that is not related with URL.

Please guide me to achieve that goal, a different approach is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a function to get breadcrumb from URL and assuming breadcrumb is, when is it, customize by hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter hooks, you just have to call this hook :

```
// Allow modules to alter the breadcrumb, if possible, as that is much
// faster than rebuilding an entirely new active trail.
drupal_alter('menu_breadcrumb', $active_trail, $item);
```

If this isn't enough to fix your problem, you can also see this contribution on github which seems great regarding the default breadcrumb construction in Drupal : https://gist.github.com/arshad/5490042#file-gistfile1-php-L12

Hope that helps :)